# slideDown function not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two div elements, when mouse enters on the div1, div2 should slide down and when mouse leaves div1, div2 should slide up.

But, in my function slide down function is not working properly

below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#text1").mouseenter(function(){      
        $("#text2").slideDown("slow");

    });
$("#text1").mouseleave(function(){      
        $("#text2").slideUp("slow");

    });
});
</script>

<style> 
#text1 {
    border:2px solid #ff0000;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #9FF;
    position:relative;
}
#text2 {
display: none;
    border:2px solid #ff0000;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #FF0;
    position:absolute;
    top:8px;
    left:8px;

}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="text1">text</div>
<div id="text2">video</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Please help on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. Thank you for all your time and help.

Below is the solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#text1").hover(function(){      
        $("#text2").slideDown("slow");

    });
$("#text2").mouseleave(function(){      
        $("#text2").slideUp("slow");

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`.stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) apart from that rest of your code works. i.e.

```
$("#text2").stop(true).slideDown("slow");
```

> Stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#text1").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#text2").stop(true).slideDown("slow");

  }).mouseleave(function() {
    $("#text2").stop(true).slideUp("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
#text1 {
  border: 2px solid #ff0000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #9FF;
  position: relative;
}
#text2 {
  display: none;
  border: 2px solid #ff0000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #FF0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text1">text</div>
<div id="text2">video</div>
```

Comment: div2 needs to replace div1 completely until cursor in the div1 area

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)** to stop currently running animation.Also you need to bind mouseleave event to both div and check that the mouse is over the `#text2` or `#text1` using **[`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var text2 = $("#text2"),
    text = $("#text1");
  text.mouseenter(function() {
    text2.stop().slideDown("slow");
  })
  $("#text1,#text2").mouseleave(function() {
    if (text2.is(':not(:hover)')&&text.is(':not(:hover)'))
      text2.stop().slideUp("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
#text1 {
  border: 2px solid #ff0000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #9FF;
  position: relative;
}
#text2 {
  display: none;
  border: 2px solid #ff0000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #FF0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text1">text</div>
<div id="text2">video</div>
```

Comment: div2 needs to replace div1 completely until cursor in the div1 area

Comment: Thank you @Pranav, I found solution. Please check above answer.

Comment: @ArunKumarM : ok , it will not work if you leave before the animation is completing, that if mouse pointer is not entered to #text2